# Groovy and JPA preventing Spring Boot CrudRepository from doing inserts

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, groovy

I have a (Groovy) Spring Boot app that talks to a H2 in-memory DB (but don't think that matters). I have the following `GroceryItem` entity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id
}

@Canonical
@TupleConstructor(includeSuperProperties = true)
@ToString(includeSuperProperties = true)
@Entity(name = 'grocery_items')
@AttributeOverrides([
        @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column=@Column(name="grocery_item_id"))
])
class GroceryItem extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = 'grocery_item_name')
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    String name

    @Column(name = 'grocery_item_qty')
    @NotNull
    Integer quantity
}
```

And then a `CrudRepository` interface for it:

```
interface GroceryItemPersistor extends CrudRepository<GroceryItem, Long> {
    @Query('FROM grocery_items WHERE grocery_item_name = :name')
    GroceryItem findByName(@Param('name') String name)

    @Query('FROM grocery_items')
    List<GroceryItem> getAllGroceries()
}
```

However for some reason this `CrudRepository`'s `save(...)` method is only updating and allowing me to ever insert one `GroceryItem` into the database. Meaning if I run this code:

```
GroceryItem olives = new GroceryItem(1L, '123456', 'Olives', 6)
groceryItemPersistor.save(olives)

List<GroceryItem> allItems = groceryItemPersistor.getAllGroceries()
log.info("There are ${allItems.size()} grocery items.")
log.info("${allItems.first().name} are in there right now")

GroceryItem cheeseWedges = new GroceryItem(2L, '067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00', 'Cheese Wedges', 4)
groceryItemPersistor.save(cheeseWedges)

allItems = groceryItemPersistor.getAllGroceries()
log.info("There are ${allItems.size()} grocery items.")
log.info("${allItems.first().name} are in there right now")
```

I get the following output on the console:

```
There are 1 grocery items.
Olives are in there right now.
There are 1 grocery items.
Cheese Wedges are in there right now.
```

What do I have to modify in my `GroceryItem` and/or `BaseEntity` classes to get `save(...)` properly inserting and not updating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was creating a primary key and saving it instead of letting JPA creating my `@Generated` key for me upon calling `save`. Changing my entity instantiations to have a `null` id:

```
GroceryItem bananas = new GroceryItem(null, '067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00', 'Bananas', 12)
```

...fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

After creating an olives item with a primary key of 1, you are passing the same primary key when creating cheeseWedges.

```
GroceryItem cheeseWedges = new GroceryItem(1L, '067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00', 'Cheese Wedges', 4)
```

Do not set the primary key when trying to create a new item. If you set it, JPA will try to update an item in the table which has the same primary key.

Comment: Thanks @Ishan (+1) **very** sorry for the confusion here but I made a *critical* copy-n-paste error. Please see my edit! I **am** saving the "Cheese Wedge" with a *different* primary key (2L) and still JPA/Hibernate/Spring is only allowing a single item to be saved/updated.